# NoReverseMatch at /event/vent_detail/3/myguest/

Tags: python, django

New to Django and can't figure this out, I'm using a header to view event details such as myguest list and keep getting this error, please help :)

NoReverseMatch at /event/vent_detail/3/myguest/
Reverse for 'vent_detail_myguest' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['event/vent_detail/(?P\d+)/myguest/$']

(views.py)

```
def vent_detail_myguests(request,pk):
    current_vent = Vent.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user_vent = current_vent.myguest
    myguests = user_vent.users.all()
    return render(request, 'event/vent_detail_myguest.html', {'myguests': myguests})
```

(urls.py)

```
re_path(r'^vent_detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/myguest/$', vent_detail_myguests, name='vent_detail_myguest'),
```

(header_template.html)

```
<a class="gaelvents" href="{% url 'event:vent_detail_myguest' vent.pk %}">MyGuests</a>
```

(vent_detail_myguest.html)

```
{% for object in myguests %}
    <div class="single-guest-container">
        <a class="username" href="{% url 'guest:profile_view' pk=object.pk %}">{{object.username}}</a>
        <a class="profilepic" href=""><img class="profilepic" src="{% static 'guest/images/logo.png' %}"></a>
        <a class="remove" href="{% url 'guest:connect_guest' adding='remove' pk=object.pk %}">Remove<a/>
    </div>  
{% endfor %}
```

(models.py)

```
class Vent(models.Model):
    event = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False, unique=True)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    myguest = models.ForeignKey(MyGuest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.event

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['event']
```

Comment: Can you try to add the `Vent` object inside the context with `vent` key? I believe the header is trying to access a unknown variable when issuing `vent.pk`

Comment: Hi! thanks for getting back to me, i think i tried that and it didn't solve the issue can you explain exactly how i do that? to make sure i have done it correctly, thanks